# Designing a database for car dealerships

Tags: database-design, composite-types

I am starting in designing a database for car dealerships (plural).  I graduated recently and this is my first gig.

The idea is that I am designing a backend that couple of dealerships will use. So we have different dealerships which might have couple of branches,  they have a list of car they are selling.

What I am struggling with are the cars and its parts because those are the information that will be pulled out of the database and published on different websites. This is how i started thinking about the Engine part:

[image]

Here I am pulling into different tables specs that might get duplicated like number of cylinders,
horsepower etc. There might be that two cars that are the same model and year have different engines for example.

Or should I do something more simple like this:
[image]

The idea is that for example two Toyota Corolla who are exactly the same type
and year have different specs for the engines.

Another idea that i got from looking through google how other people have done similar systems:
[image]

with the carParts table we can have different parts for the Same car, it works well when you want to say for example that this Toyota Corolla has Air Conditioning,  if we add a number variable in the carParts you can also use it for example saying that the Same Toyota Corolla car has a different horsepower amount than another car.

I am struggling with visualizing this and I am unsure about the timing system,  because if a certain car has a belt instead of a chain it has additional information that the timing chain does not.

Am I going in the right direction? If there are any Database-Yodas out there any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated :)

## ================================
Update

So I have changed the design,  it is much simpler.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTPAMJ9MzdY

I found this video about complex relationships which answered two questions I had:

1. Things that have is A relationship,  parent child relationship and I do think i could use that concept for something like the timing equipment in cars that can either be chain or belt
2. Things that are composed of multiple parts like a computer that can have processor, motherboard and so on. I could use it for the car concept and split Car into Engine, drive circuit instead of going further and splitting everything inside Engine in its own tables.

Normalization and redundency is more complex topic than I first thought.  When thinking about cars many things are the same but the same car, manufactured the same year could have a new engine with different specs so how much can you really prevent redundency and when are really two cars a duplicate of each other.
I was also thinking at first that the a car sales company can sell many instances of the same car but that is not the issue, they each have their own ID,  the exact same car can be sold by two different car sales companies, that you have to take into account.

I am sorry for my ramblings,  writing what I know makes me understand the topic more. If anyone how more input please feel free to comment.
Maybe I put my updated schema here later, It is all in icelandic at the moment :)

Comment: Your first design is way to denormalised -- you don't want to move each possible value to a separate table with a foreign key. But I would retain the engine table, with the other columns as simple attributes. Then each model of car can have an engine -- but be aware that many models of cars are available with engine choices. Check recent cars on Wikipedia and you will see more information about how they are categorised -- in modern manufacturing many cars are based on a platform which may be available as different models of cars from different manufacturers, but they all share a common base.

Answer (score 1):

From your first example to your second example you went between two opposite extremes of [Normalization](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html), and likely you want something in between.

For example, you'll obviously need a `Cars` table and there will be different kinds of things relevant to a **Car**, such as an **Engine**, **Make, Model, & Year**, maybe **Paint** (for type, color, style) etc. Some of these things make sense to normalize out such as the **Engine**, because as you see there are a number of **Engine** specific attributes. So you would want to have an `Engines` table. But you shouldn't over normalize things like the **Stroke** and **Cylinders** into their own tables because those are basically only one or two attributes that apply to all (or most) **Engines**. Things like **Make, Model, & Year** are probably ok to leave inside your `Cars` table, since they generally apply to all cars.

If you wanted to store information about the **Car Paint** then you probably would want to normalize the **Paint** attributes into their own table because there's multiple attributes for **Paint**. But having only one `Paint` attributes table is probably sufficient (as opposed to making a separate table for each **Paint** attribute).

So the point being normalize your tables when there are multiple related attributes that apply to most of the same object type. Don't overly normalize by breaking every attribute into its own table. Also it's ok if one of your related attributes doesn't always apply to any instance of the object type, as long as it's generally applicable. E.g. your questions regarding a Timing Chain vs Timing Belt. Unless there's a ton of attributes that apply to one and not the other, it's probably ok to store both in the same table (which likely would be the `Engine` table).

In regards to your last example, it depends on what the use cases and goals are of your system. In my previous example that details a more granular system that might be useful for a car manufacturer or the repair shop of a manufacturer. A `CarParts` table makes sense for storing all the different kinds of parts there are, with generically applicable information such as Description. It may be moreso applicable to a parts store that sells replacement parts (though could also be used in a car manufacturing system).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I do see how I was overnormalizing.  By looking at other threads about similar systems I did see they did not go this far.

If i have Engine as a separate table and would leave it like that with no other tables.  Would that not result in redundant records? Like two entries where everything is the same except for 1 attribute? By starting this project i realized how little I know about normalization :P

Comment: @Snorrinn No problem! Repeated values is not necessarily the same as redundant data. I know it's hard to conceptualize when you're learning but take for instance the attribute *amount of cylinders*. It's a numerical value with no finite set, so there is little to no benefit refactoring it into it's own table. If two `Engines` are exactly the same except for *amount of cylinders*, it doesn't matter that they share the same `CC` which is also a numerical value that is an infinite set. At most you may normalize related attributes together into their own table, like `CC` and `CylinderAmount`.

Comment: @Snorrinn Normalizing fields into their own table is usually for two purposes: 1) Maintainability - If it's a finite set of values which can possibly change one day (e.g. `Colors`) it may be easier to maintain in its own table (you only need to update one record if *Blue* becomes *SkyBlue* one day. 2) Performance - Same root reason as #1, by only needing to update 1 row instead of all rows `WHERE Color = 'Blue'`, it's quicker to do. Fields with an infinite set of values (generally numerical fields) don't usually make sense to normalize into their own table, by themselves.